# JSF form needs to update a field

Tags: date, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF form with 2 dates. Start Date is required.

2 things I would need:

- When the End date is filled in --> Then the Days should be calculated and filled in.
- When the Days are filled in (example: 31) --> Then the End date should be filled in.

How can this be done in JSF?

[image]

My form:

```
<h:form id="date">

    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <p:outputLabel for="startDate" value="Start Date"/>
        <p:calendar id="startDate" value="#{dateBean.startDate}" required="true" pattern="d MMM yyyy"/>
        <p:message for="startDate"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="endDate" value="End Date"/>
        <p:calendar id="endDate" value="#{dateBean.endDate}" pattern="d MMM yyyy"/>
        <p:message for="endDate"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="days" value="Days"/>
        <p:inputText id="days" value="#{dateBean.days}"/>
        <p:message for="days"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

My Bean:

```
@Named(value = "dateBean")
@SessionScoped
public class DateBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private Integer days;

    //getters and setters
    ...
```

Comment: According to your date fields, is the format: MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Correctly: I used the default format: MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Are you writing the dates or are you choosing the dates via the popup calendar?

Comment: I'm using the primefaces popup calendar, but i can also edit the date manually.

Comment: for When the End date is filled in --> Then the Days should be calculated and filled in.

This link provides exactly what you want : http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/calendar/calc.xhtml

Comment: OmniFaces could really save you a couple of hours with their collection of EL functions about Dates. http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Dates

Comment: @Magnilex: please don't put [java] tag on the question as long as the problem is not reproducible with a plain Java application class with main() method. [java] users are incapable of understanding and answering JSF questions and would generally only post nonsense comments which confuse the OP, and/or rep hungry nitwits would even post misleading answers based on failed Google attempts and they sometimes even get confusingly upvoted by other [java] users. I removed the [java] tag again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rather go with the built-in Primefaces way of doing this. There is an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) event called `dateSelect` which will fire when the date has changed:

> Calendar provides a dateSelect ajax behavior event to execute an instant ajax selection whenever a date  is  selected. If you define a method as a  listener, it will be invoked by passing an `org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent` instance.

Using this, `endDate` would look like (ignoring the date format property, which seems wrong):

```
<p:calendar id="endDate" value="#{dateBean.endDate}">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{dateBean.handleDateSelect}" update="days" />
</p:calendar>
```

This would register a listener to be called once a new date is selected. It would call your backing bean, and then re-render the `days` input field to display the new value.

In `DateBean` you would then implement this method to perform the logic to happen upon date selection:

```
public void handleDateSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    Date date = (Date) event.getObject();
    // the below method would calculate the difference in days between the dates
    calculateDaysIfStartDateIsFilled(date);
}
```

For the `days` tag, I would use [`p:event`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/event.xhtml) to trigger an event on *change*, that is when the value in the field changes:

```
<p:inputText id="days" value="#{dateBean.days}">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="endDate" listener="#{dateBean.handleDaysChange}" />
</p:inputText>
```

And add the following method in `DateBean` to perform the logic:

```
public void handleDaysChange() {
    calculateToDateIfStartDateIsFilled();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Javascript `onchange` event and just update the field with the desired result.

```
<p:calendar id="endDate" value="#{dateBean.endDate}" onchange="alertDateSelected()"/>
```

[To calculate days between 2 dates in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

[To get date + days in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime)

Answer (score -2):

One suggestion would be to use [JSTL format library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html)

It may guide you to your requirments, so you can do something like this:

```
<fmt:parseNumber
    value="${(dateBean.endDate - dateBean.startDate) / (1000*60*60*24) }"
    integerOnly="true" var="daysDifference"/>
```

And set your field value as: (Update via jQuery/javascript triggering the change on the End Date field)

```
<p:inputText id="days" value="#{daysDifference}"/>
```